# Why I can't see the old facebook likes on my website after I change the address from http to https?

Tags: html, facebook, .htaccess

I changed the address of my website from http to https.

I made for all pages a 301 redirect from http to https, meta og url is pointet to the http and if you like on our page it shares https.

The problem is that it not show the old likes, only then new from https if I disable meta og url. It do not combine.

The question is how to show the old likes and the new likes on my new https address?

Comment: show your html please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likes depend on `og:url`, so if you change it to https, it will be a new set of likes. They don´t just get moved to the new URL. You can only try using the http URL in the `og:url` tag to keep your old likes.

Comment: I tried that already and yes is a way, but I think I have a problem in my code.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it should work automatically. Did you check your URL at Facebook´s Debug Tool?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/